# How to put a form panel within a window in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs

im trying to put a form inside a window, im working on the example of the web desktop,i add a new entry on the start menu an that entry it is supposed to call a window and inside that window there must be a form, but it seems to be unable to display the form inside the window. Im pastying the code of the form and the module that creates the window.

Now the issue its solved so im going to put the solution right here inside the code.

Code for the panel

```
Ext.define('MyDesktop.HelloWorldWindow',{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'firstName',
            anchor:'100%'
        },
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            name: 'lastName',
            anchor:'100%'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
            name: 'birthDate',
            anchor:'100%'
        }
    ]
});
```

Code for the module that creates the window.

```
Ext.define('MyDesktop.HelloWorldWindowModule', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.desktop.Module',

    init : function(){
        this.launcher = {
            text: 'Hello World',
            iconCls:'bogus',
            handler : this.createWindow,
            scope: this,
            id:'hello-world'
        }
    },

    createWindow : function(src){
        var desktop = this.app.getDesktop();
        var win = desktop.getWindow('hello-world');
        var hello = new MyDesktop.HelloWorldWindow();
        if(!win){

            win = desktop.createWindow({
                id: 'helloWorld',
                title:src.text,
                width:640,
                height:480,
                iconCls: 'bogus',
                animCollapse:false,
                constrainHeader:true,
                items: [hello]
            });
        }
        win.show();
        return win;
    }
});
```

And just displays this when i click the "Hello World" option in the menu.
[image: Web Desktop]

And now the magick works ;)
[image: It works!]

Comment: try `items: [hello]` -- items should be plural, and hello is not a property of this

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually that was one of the problems i had, that, and curiously the constructor function was giving troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `createWindow` add `layout:'fit'` and change item to `items:[hello]`

Comment: Thanks also for answer, the layout property was usefull to!